# Can't access WiFi extender IP address for settings configuration

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking, wifi-configuration, wireless-extender

I am connected through my wifi extender, but when I do 192.168.0.1, it goes to the actual router configuration page, not my WiFi extender's configuration page.

The default IP address for my WiFi extender is 192.168.1.1 according to the manual
https://www.engeniustech.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/EAP1300-User-Manual.pdf

But I get blocked, saying the connection was refused or took too long.

I even got a wifi scanner for all the connections and IPs on the 192.168.x.x network, and tried putting all of those IPs into my internet browser. All of them say the connection was refused or took too long.

Some info:
 - I'm trying to add security/password to my WiFi extender. Right now, it is publically accessible.
 - I am on a windows laptop and the network is considered a Windows public network, not private.

How do I access my EnGenius Wifi extender settings?

Comment: Sometimes, for security, you cannot administrate a router/access point over wifi, only wired ethernet. This reduces the chances of a hacker being able to get into it. Try Ethernet.

Comment: That would be ethernet from the extender, correct?

Comment: On page 8 of the manual, https://www.engeniustech.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/EAP1300-User-Manual.pdf  it says `The following are the Minimum System Requirements in order to configure the device:
 Computer with an Ethernet interface or wireless network capability
` I guess it's still worth a try.